# Sumif value is in year

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have list of dates and values:

```
01.01.2016   100

01.02.2017   200

01.03.2017   300
```

What i want is now if the the year is 2017 count the value.
Result: 200 + 300 = 500

This is a formula i tried:

```
=SUMIF($F5:$F,"<="&$A2,AF5:AF)
```

The issue is that google sheet can not compare a date and a year. When i change the date from 01.02.2017 to 2017 it works.

If i try to get the year of the date it doesnt work:

```
=SUMIF(YEAR($F5:$F),"="&$A2,AF5:AF)
```

How can compare a date with a year? Or is there an other way?

Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not related to programming. It should have been posted on [webapps.se] instead.

Comment: A bit of an old question, but found it while looking for the easiest solution and thought I'ld add that you can do this with sumif/sumifs easily. Just turn:

    =SUMIF(YEAR($F5:$F),"="&$A2,AF5:AF)
Into:

    =arrayformula(SUMIF(YEAR($F5:$F),"="&$A2,AF5:AF))

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try this formula:

`=SUM(FILTER(B:B,YEAR(A:A)=2017))`

And also please try this:

`=QUERY(A:B,"select year(A), sum(B) where A is not null group by year(A)")`

[image]

Comment: Thanks the first formula worked well but the second does not work.

Comment: Thanks! `QUERY` is great for someone who knows SQL already.